# What are the 1x1 pixel windows are for?

Tags: xorg, gtk, window-manager

In the output of `xwininfo -root -tree`, I observe a 1x1 window accompanying almost any other "normal" window. Like this:

[image]

What are these windows for? Is there a way to obtain XID of such window (except adding 1 to parent's XID)?

Comment: In 'xprop' of the parent window I have found that the 1x1 window is specified as `_NET_WM_USER_TIME_WINDOW`. And the 1x1 window itself has a single property. It is, as expected, `_NET_WM_USER_TIME`.

Comment: So the window may be created solely for one reason, holding `_NET_WM_USER_TIME` property. I wonder if it's true? The reason I need it is actually a focus issue in may application. I wouldn't go into much details here but calling `XSetInputFocus` for this 1x1 window fixes the issue. But why?